# flutter_html onLinkTap function giving error

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I am new to Flutter and working on build html widget using flutter_html with version flutter_html^3.0.0-beta.2. With the recent version updates I am getting one error for onLinkTap function.

Following is the code:

```
static Widget getHTMLWidget(String htmlContent, Function onTap) {
 return Html(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  data: htmlContent,
  onLinkTap: (
    String? url, 
    RenderContext renderContext,
    Map<String, String> attributes, element
  ) async {
    onTapFunction();
  },
 );
}
```

Error from IDE is:

`The argument type 'void Function(String?, Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?, Map<String, String>, Element?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable`

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

As per the latest version code changes we need to call the function like below,

```
Html(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 data: htmlContent,
 onLinkTap: (url, _, __) {
  onTapFunction();
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This version isn't ready for production. It's probably that the documentation isn't ready yet.

The latest release version of this package is `flutter_html: ^2.2.1` according to the docs on `dart.pub` [as you can check here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/versions)

And if this worked before, maybe the arguments of this method were changed and we couldn't know without the docs. If you really need to test this beta version, try to open an Issue on their Github Repository.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a discussion with their support team and was able to fix it. I have added my answer.